Laplacian is surjective from $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(B)$ to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(B)$
Let $B$ denote the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(B)$ represent the space of smooth functions on $B$.
Is the Laplacian operator $\Delta$ surjective as a map from $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(B)$ to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(B)$?
I am only able to find a reference for the case $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\overline{B})\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\overline{B})$ or $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Look up the following: elliptic operator, fundamental solution.

You  should provide references for the results you know. Others could use it.

@PiotrHajlasz For example, the case of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\overline{B})$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be found in Theorem 1.13 and Corollary 1.19 in https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/pdelect23.pdf.

@Nandor: Even though the functions in question do not have to be integrable?

EVERY non-zero linear partial differential operator with constant coefficients is surjective on $\mathscr C^\infty(\Omega)$ for CONVEX open sets $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

@JochenWengenroth Could you provide a reference?

Corollary 10.6.8 combined with 10.6.2 in Hörmander's The Analysis of Partial Differential Operators II (the theorem is due to Malgrange).

@JochenWengenroth Thank you for your answer.

@JochenWengenroth I think it's worth putting your comments into the answer box. Then it could be accepted.


Every non-zero linear partial differential operator with constant coefficients $P(\partial)$ (with a polynomial $P$ in $n$ variables) is surjective as an operator on $C^\infty(\Omega)$ for every convex open set $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

A proof of this theorem of Malgrange is, e.g., in Hörmander's The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators, Corollary 10.6.8 conbined with 10.6.2.
This theorem is in purely classical terms but its proof heavily relies on distribution theory and can be split in a functional analytic part (where $P(\partial)$ can be replaced by any operator $T:C^\infty(\Omega)\to C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that the smooth functions with compact support are in the range, then $T$ is surjective if Hörmander's convexity for supports holds for the transposed $T^t$ which acts on distributions with compact supports, i.e., for every compact set $K\subseteq \Omega$ there is another one $L$ such that supp$(T^t(u))\subseteq K$ implies supp$(u)\subseteq L$) and a Fourier analytic part which is used to solve $P(\partial)f=\varphi$ if $\varphi$ has compact support (by convolution with a fundamental solution) and to show that convex sets are always convex for supports.
